# IdentityServer4 with EmberJs

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, identityserver4

I have configured emberjs to use IDS4 before but I use it with simple auth and torii - however - on the site I am building now I do not want a pop up for auth and i also want to allow users to register through my site.

WRT the 1st issue - no popup - I can see that I can use

```
mgr.signinRedirect();
```

As shown in https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/7_JavaScriptClient/src/JavaScriptClient/wwwroot/app.js#L41

But that would mean hosting the login page as part of IDS and that means maintaining the CSS, markup and JS to make it look like it's a part of the main site - this I do not want to have to do.

What is the way to handle this?

The EmberJs site has a .NET webapi backing it - is there a way to POST the username / pass to the API and have the API proxy the auth?

WRT the 2nd issue - registration - I guess the question is - is there a way to do the same as above? send the new user details to the API and have that issue the request to IDS to create the user?

[UPDATE]

From looking around the quickstarts it seems there is no way to allow a JS client to register and authenticate without using a popup or a redirect to the views hosted on IDS... am i right?

This is crazy...

Comment: have you figured it out?

Comment: I gave up and did the redirect. IMO it's a bit naff but I don't want to use a flow that's going to open up vulnerabilities